# Change the [conditional-formatting] tag to not only be about Google Spreadsheets

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just asked a question about conditional formatting in Microsoft Office Online. I added the [conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting) tag but then saw that it apparently only relates to Google Spreadsheets.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the dim past when that tag was created, the only web-based spreadsheet app of any note was Google Spreadsheets.

Now that there are others and they're gaining popularity, it probably makes sense to "de-couple" [conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting) from Google Sheets.

We would probably prefer a tag specific to the app, but both `[excel-online-conditional-formatting]` and `[google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting]` are far too long.

We have [formulas](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulas), which is generically for formulas in online spreadsheet apps. It makes sense to me to do the same for [conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting).

Comment: I've tweaked the wiki for [tag:conditional-formatting] to be more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Tag excerpts and wiki tags are created and edited by the community, so rather than a bug it's about the result of the Web Applications' community contributions.

According to the following search, at this time there is only one question include [conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting) and [excel-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel-online) for a question that doesn't include [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets):

[[conditional-formatting] -[google-spreadsheets] excel is:question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bconditional-formatting%5D+-%5Bgoogle-spreadsheets%5D+excel+is%3Aquestion)

By the other hand there are 74 questions that have [conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting) and [google-spreadsheets]

[[conditional-formatting] [google-spreadsheets] is:question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bconditional-formatting%5D+%5Bgoogle-spreadsheets%5D+is%3Aquestion)

## References

- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)
- [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)